# dnaof() - inheritance made easy, my own make inheritance tool

Tags: javascript, inheritance

https://github.com/exebook/dnaof

I created this simple inheritance tool for JavaScript, could any one with deep knowledge in JavaScript prototyped inheritance review it?

Here is the library itself:

```
kindof = function(K) {
    function X() {}
    if (K != undefined) X.prototype = new K
    X.can = X.prototype
    return X
}
dnaof = function(x, f) {
    var p = x.__proto__
    x.__proto__ = p.__proto__
    var r = p.__proto__[f].apply(x)
    x.__proto__ = p
    return r
}
```

And here is the example usage to demonstrate what it can do:

```
require('./dnaof')

// create a kind of idiot without ancestor:

var idiot = kindof()

// tell what it can do:

idiot.can.say = function() { return this.name + ' can chat' }
idiot.can.rest = function() { console.log('bzzzz.z.z.z... (' + this.name + ')') }

// a new kind of smart inherits from a kind of idiot

var smart = kindof(idiot)

// he can also say something:

smart.can.say = function() {
    // he can say something new, and he can say the same thing as an idiot can:
    return dnaof(this, 'say') + ', ' + this.name + ' can talk'
}

// a kind of a genious can do the same things as an idiot and smart can, and even more:

var genious = kindof(smart)
genious.can.say = function() {
    return dnaof(this, 'say') + ', ' + this.name + ' can discuss'
}

// instantiate three persons:

var bob = new idiot
var alice = new smart
var candy = new genious

// assign properties, because to make life simpler we do not initialize anything during creation:

bob.name = 'bob'
alice.name = 'alice'
candy.name = 'candy'

// let them talk:

console.log(bob.say())
console.log(alice.say())
console.log(candy.say())

// let them take some rest:

alice.rest(), bob.rest(), candy.rest()
```

Comment: Just a tip, `__proto__` is non-standard. See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: I know, but is there a better way?

Comment: Unfortunately, I would probably rewrite the whole library for something else, however here's a few hints. Rather than using `new` to setup the prototype chain, you can use `Object.create` in every modern browsers. Also, to dynamically get the *parent class*, you can do `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))`. With these changes you can stop using `__proto__`. Also, you should opt for a syntax that doesn't require you to write `obj.can` all the time to define new members.

Answer (score 2):

From a once over, and borrowing from the comments:

- `__proto__` is bad news, MDN mentions this in a [big red box of doom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).
- There is no means to pass parameters to the constructor, that does not make it simple
- `X`, `x`, `k`, `r` and `p` are terrible variable names
- `dnaof` is an unfortunate name
- lowerCamelCase is good for you, `kindof` -> `kindOf`,
- You can get the parent class thru `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))` in `dnaof`
- I have mixed feelings about the `can` trick. It is shorter than typing `prototype`, but it's also a candidate for nameclashes.
- You have no comments at all in your code, combined with 1 letter variables that makes for not good code
- If I were to build an OO library, I would also play with `constructor` and add some support for private.

All in all, this is something I would not mind using, but that I would hate to have to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Actually I switched completely from using "prototype", now 'dnaof' will store each function super-call in it self.